# Регулярное выражение в jquery

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строчка

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z?-?\ \-]/gi, ''));              
                if($.trim($(this).val()).search(/^[a-z?-?\ \-]{2,}$/gi) == 0) {
                    form.styleField($(this), true);
                    form.currentForm.status = true;                                     
                }
```

Которая разрешает вводиьт только английские буквы, как добавить русские буквы?

Comment: как ни странно: `а-я` :-D

Comment: `ё` не забывайте...

Comment: @Grundy [^а-яa-z?-?\ \-] вот так?

Comment: `[^а-яёa-z?-?\ \-]` вот так

Comment: @VenZell, минутку поищу дубликат :-) да, точно :-) `ё` выбивается

Comment: @Grundy, уже нашел и отметил копией

Comment: @VenZell, еще один для разнообразия :)